# execute bash files when previous ones have finished to run

Tags: bash, jobs, execute, slurm

Hello I would need help

In fact I need to execute several bash files ex:

```
file1.sh
file2.sh
file3.sh 
file4.sh
```

those file will generate data that will be used for another bash file call `final.sh`

So in order to gain time I want to execute the `fileNb.sh`  files sumultany on a cluster by doing :

**`for file in file*.sh; do sbatch $file; done`**

, and then when all job have been done, I would like to execute automatically the `final.sh` file.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Send to the queue the final script with dependencies against the other scripts.

Comment: Can you share a script in order to add dependencies options ?

Comment: `sbatch -d afterok:$JobID1:$JobID2:$JobIDN final.sh`

Comment: @Poshi is it possible to do : ```sbatch --dependency=afterok:file1.sh:file2.sh:file3.sh final.sh`` ??  Because I get  ```sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem```

Comment: No, you have to use the job(s) ID(s).

Comment: ok I see, I created another post If you have the answer maybe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625865/get-job-id-and-put-them-into-a-bash-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One clean option is to reorganise the set of jobs as a [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) and then add a [dependency](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_dependency) for final job on the whole array.

Assuming `fileN.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --<some option>
#SBATCH --<some other option>

./my_program input_fileN
```

you can make this a job array. In a single submission file `file.sh`, write this

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --<some option>
#SBATCH --<some other option>
#SBATCH --array=1-4

./my_program input_file${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
```

Then run

```
JOBID=$(sbatch --parsable file.sh)
sbatch --dependency after:$JOBID final.sh
```

In case your jobs cannot be parametrised by an integer directly, create a Bash array like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --<some option>
#SBATCH --<some other option>
#SBATCH --array=0-2

ARGS=(SRR63563 SRR63564 SRR63565)

fasterq-dump --threads 10  ${ARGS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} -O /path1/path2/path3/
```

Comment: Thank you but what if in each job I have different name instead of a number ranging from 0 to 3 for instance ? how can I deal with an array ? , here is an exemple of my fileN content : ```fasterq-dump --threads 10  SRR63563 -O /path1/path2/path3/ ```;  f```asterq-dump --threads 10  SRR63564 -O /path1/path2/path3/``` ;  ```fasterq-dump --threads 10  SRR63565 -O /path1/path2/path3/ ```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
sbatch --wait file1.sh &
sbatch --wait file2.sh &
sbatch --wait file3.sh &
sbatch --wait file4.sh &
wait
sbatch final.sh
```

Or, more simply with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel -j4 sbatch --wait ::: file*.sh
sbatch final.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this no good?

```
for file in file*.sh; do sbatch $file; done; ./final.sh
```

Comment: OP was hoping to use `slurm` and to run the initial jobs *in parallel*.