# Get Job id and put them into a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, jobs, slurm

Hello for a projet I need to execute a bash file only when all previous run have been finished so I use :

```
sbatch -d afterok:$JobID1:$JobID2:$JobIDN final.sh
```

in Order to run the JobIDN I do

```
for job in Job*.sh ; do sbatch $job; done
```

Then it prints all the `jobIDs`

I just wondered if someone haave a command in order to grab these IDs and put them directly to the command :

```
sbatch -d afterok:$JobID1:$JobID2:$JobIDN final.sh
```

exemple

```
for job in Job*.sh ; do sbatch $job; done 
1
2
3


sbatch -d afterok:$1:$2:$3 final.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
for job in Job*.sh ; do sbatch --parsable $job; done | paste -s -d: | xargs -I{} sbatch --depedency afterok:{} final.sh
```

The `paste` command will gather all job IDS and write them on a single line, colon-separated, while `xargs` will take the result and insert it at the `{}` placeholder. The information about the job IDs is passed through pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the job ids in a variable and use it for your next command. Something like

```
jobs=$(seq 1 10 | awk '{ printf ":%s", $1 }')
     # \------/
 # your jobID printing function here
```

And then

```
sbatch -d afterok"$jobs" final.sh
```